# 500 internal server error when trying to execute CURL

Tags: .htaccess, laravel, curl

Hello i am having an issue here, i get a 500 internal server error when i try to execute curl on my server.  I contacted support and they claim it's my .htaccess file and there is nothing they can do about it.

This is my code:

```
$api_key = 'f7cb125a449f4f908931f360ac33b52a';
$server_ip = '162.13.170.20';
$port = '5000';
$url = "https://".$server_ip.":".$port."/api/fusion/tp/".$api_key;

// Get cURL resource
$curl = curl_init();
// Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
    CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
    CURLOPT_URL => $url,
    CURLOPT_USERAGENT => 'myTicketGH',
    CURLOPT_POST => true,
    CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
        'kuwaita' => 'malipo',
        'amount' => $calculated_total_cost,
        'mno' => $network,
        'msisdn' => $phone
    )
));
// Send the request & save response to $resp
$resp = curl_exec($curl);
// Close request to clear up some resources
curl_close($curl);

return [
    'response' => $resp
];
```

And this is my .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine on

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

    RewriteRule . index.php [L]

     RewriteEngine On
     RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
     RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Is there a **laravel** way of using CURL? Because i can't understand how there can be a problem with my .htaccess file but my application still runs.

I contacted support, apparently this is my error_log:

```
[Tue Sep 29 09:31:20 2015] [warn] [client 69.195.125.1] mod_fcgid: read data timeout in 40 seconds
[Tue Sep 29 09:31:20 2015] [error] [client 69.195.125.1] Premature end of script headers: index.php
[Tue Sep 29 09:31:20 2015] [error] [client 69.195.125.1] File does not exist: /home/mytickf1/public_html/500.shtml
[Tue Sep 29 09:31:26 2015] [warn] mod_fcgid: process 14879 graceful kill fail, sending SIGKILL
```

I should also add that my server uses a dedicated IP address.

Comment: what does your error log says ?

Comment: Can't see any related errors on my error log page in my cpanel.

Comment: Try to enable Curl  Verbose `curl_setopt($curlhandle, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, true);` does it output something meaningful ?

Comment: I just tried it, it still gives me 500 internal server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to handle the https with curl. The easiest option is to turn it off with

```
CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0
```

Because if you don't do it you will get an empty result. The 500 error is thrown when you want to work with the result because it is empty.

Comment: Tried this too, couldn't get it to work, same response,

Comment: I tested your code with googles ip and my solution worked with your code.

Comment: So could it then be the server i am posting to and not my code?

Comment: You should try to make the curl call without laravel to the server. Then you know which server is throwing the error.

Comment: Just tried it without laravel, still didn't work, if that means it's ffom the other server then do you have any idea why it throws a 500 internal server error?

Comment: What do you get as result if you print your curl result?

Comment: I do not get a result, just 500 internal server error always.

Comment: So curl timed out. Have you checked that the server is alive on this port?

Comment: Okay it seemed like a combination of several different things, one being the server i was posting too didn't have my IP on their whitelist but after that was dealt with the answer you posted made it work finally, without it i get bool(false) dunno why, thanks for your help!! :)

Answer (score -3):

You are using https protocol in your curl URL

```
$url = "https://".$server_ip.":".$port."/api/fusion/tp/".$api_key;
```

Should work with http protocol.

Comment: I don't understand, are you saying CURL won't work with https?

Comment: No. I was just suspecting https could be culprit. Are you setting authorization header as well? Please share error logs

Comment: I checked error log, there is nothing relating to this error there.

Comment: And no i am nit setting authorization header.